# matplotlib Plot X-axis with '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot a graph with the below sample, `X-axis: 'Time', Y-axis: 'Celcius'`. With the attached code, I got `[09:00:00.000000  09:05:00.000000 ... 09:30:00.000000]` at the x-axis, instead of `[2013-01-02 09:00 2013-01-02 09:05 ... 2013-01-02 09:30]`.

Does anyone know what the correct way to format x-axis to the designated format is?

```
data = {'Celcius': [36.906441135554658, 51.286294403017202], 'Time': [datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 9, 30)]}
```

---

```
def plotTemperature(self, data):
    logging.debug(data)
    
    t = data.get('Time')
    T = data.get('Celcius')
    
    years    = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
    months   = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
    days    = mdates.DayLocator()     # every day
    hours = mdates.HourLocator()      # every hour      
    minutes = mdates.MinuteLocator()  # every minute  
    yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')
    hoursFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, T)        
    
    # format the ticks
    # ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
    # ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hoursFmt)
    # ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minutes)
    
    datemin = datetime.datetime(min(t).year, min(t).month, min(t).day, min(t).hour, min(t).minute) 
    datemax = datetime.datetime(max(t).year, max(t).month, max(t).day, max(t).hour, max(t).minute)
    ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)
    
    # format the coords message box
    def temperature(x): return '$%1.2f'%x
    ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    ax.format_ydata = temperature
    ax.grid(True)
    
    # rotates and right aligns the x labels, and moves the bottom of the
    # axes up to make room for them
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```py
import dateutil
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ymdhFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
rule = mdates.rrulewrapper(dateutil.rrule.MINUTELY, interval=30)
loc = mdates.RRuleLocator(rule)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ymdhFmt)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19680010/2) to the question [matplotlib Plot X-axis with '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680010/matplotlib-plot-x-axis-with-y-m-d-hm) by the OP [twfx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975984/twfx) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>